# postgresql : reset date to the first day of the month from a table

Tags: postgresql, date

I'm trying to reset the date I get from a table which is in numeric form. Right now I get only the date from the numeric but how do I list the date in such a way that all the days are in date are set to the first day of the month?
Ex : 2018/06/26 should be listed as 2018/06/01

This is what I've tried to list the dates from a particular date :

```
select to_timestamp(date::numeric/1000)::date from timeentry;
```

Would greatly appreciate your help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `date_trunc()`

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot :)